# 'Calculating area and circumference of a circuit' program in c ... strange output

Tags: c, switch-statement, scanf

I'm working on this program that ask user to enter radius of a circuit then ask them to choose what he want to calculate: area, circumference, or volume of cylinder..

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
float radius=0.0,height=0.0;
char choice,quit;
const float pi=3.1415658;

do
{
printf("Enter radius : \n");
scanf("%f",&radius);

printf("\n\nWhat do you want to calc.?\nArea of circuit --> press A\n"
"Circumference of circuit --> press C\nVolume of cylinder --> press V\nQuit --> Q\n");

scanf("%c",&choice);

switch (choice)
{
case 'A':
   printf("Area = %.5f\n",radius*radius*pi);
   break;
case 'C':
   printf("Circumference = %.5f\n",2*radius*pi);
   break;
case 'V':
    printf("Enter Hight : \n");
    scanf("%f",&height);
   printf("Volume of cylinder = %.5f\n",radius*radius*pi*height);
   break;
case 'Q':
    quit='y';
   break;
default:
    printf("default!!\n");
   break;
}
}while(quit != 'y');

return 0;
}
```

but when I run the program

```
Enter radius :
3

What do you want to calc.?
Area of circuit --> press A
Circumference of circuit --> press C
Volume of cylinder --> press V
Quit --> Q
/*here before I choose anything the next line appears, skipping reading the choice*/
default!!
Enter radius :
```

so why it skips reading the choice of the user and jump directly to the default ?
what's the problem ??

Comment: Aside from the error in using `scanf`, you need to initialize `quit`.

Comment: The proper way to debug this problem is to step through the program in a debugger, examining relevant values at each questionable step, or to insert statements to print values during execution to show what is going on. Asking others to debug it for you is inappropriate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because when you use `scanf` to read the radius, the newline you press to end that input is still in the input buffer. So when you later use `scanf` to read a character, it reads that newline.

The simple solution is to tell the latter `scanf` to skip any leading whitespace. This is done by adding a space to the `scanf` format code:

```
scanf(" %c", &choice);
/*     ^           */
/*     |           */
/* Note space here */
```

Comment: You know what, it worked but I don't understand why?
First--I understand that "when you use scanf to read the radius, the newline you press to end that input is still in the input buffer", but what is the problem with that ?
Second--What is the problem when scanf read the new line? I mean who that would effect the whole program 
Finally--You mean that we need to tell the latter scanf to skip the "newline" character right? How can this happen by just adding a space to the scanf format code?
Sorry for disturbance

Comment: @Salahuddin If the next character in the input buffer is a newline, and you want to read the next character, you will get that newline and the input-reading function (in your case the `scanf` function) will happily return with that.

Comment: @Salahuddin Also, when you have a space in a `scanf` format string, it tells `scanf` to skip all characters for which the `isspace` function returns true, and newline is such a space character.

Comment: @Salahuddin Of and by the way, you might want to read [this reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf).